# How is the name Kronecker pronounced?

Tags: pronunciation

His name seems to be pronounced by English speaking physicists, who probably do not speak German, as ‘Kronnecker’. What is the correct pronunciation?

Comment: look at this link [www.howtopronounce.com/kronecker](https://www.howtopronounce.com/kronecker)

Comment: @SwissCodeMen: What you hear at this site is an American pronunciation. But Leopold Kronecker was a German mathematician, so his name should be pronounced German.

Comment: Right, though I'd say the American pronunciation actually becomes good enough if only you change the `r`-sound, which is in German always [guttural](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Guttural_R) (in `kr`) or omitted (in `er`), but never an alveolar/postalveolar approximant (except in some dialects).

Comment: In general, for English speakers a reasonable approximation is allowable when names involve sounds not normally used in English. The emphasis being on 'reasonable', for example "Euler" as "oiler" is okay, while "Euler" as "yooler" will provoke condescending looks. The most trouble comes from ö and ü with "Gödel" pronounced something like 'girdle'. Math is generally considered difficult enough without having to be a linguist as well, considering you have to deal with names from all over the world.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Leopold Kronecker was a German mathematician and his brother Hugo Kronecker was a German physiologist. Both were born in Liegnitz which belonged to Prussia when they were born, but now belongs to Poland and is spelled *Legnica* now.

Both were born and grew up in a German speaking society and both of them lived in a region that became Germany later. So, if you want to pronounce their last name correctly, you have to pronounce it according to the German rules of pronunciation.

The name is a compound word, built from

1. Kron
2. Ecker

The first part is the stem of the word *Krone* (engl: crown). The pronunciation of *Krone* is [ˈkʁoːnə], so *Kron* has to be prnonouced  [ˈkʁoːn].

American people who pronounce this syllable often add an [u] after the [o] and create a diphthong this way, but the correct German pronunciation of *Kron* doesn't contain an [u] sound or a diphthong. It's just a strait long [o].

The second part "Ecker" is the German name for *beech nut,* this is the fruit of beech trees. More often you will hear *Buchecker* instead of *Ecker* (because the German name of *beech* is *Buche*), but both words are valid names for this nut.

- "Ecker" is pronounced [ˈɛkɐ]

Join it together and you get *Kronecker,* the main stress is on the first syllable, so all in all you get:

"Kronecker" [ˈkʁoːnɛkɐ]

Comment: It may be a variety, but the vocalized <er> in Germany usually becomes an [ə].

Comment: @amadeusamadeus So *bitte* and *bitter* are homophonous? That strikes me as unusual. – I would add the glottal stop in front of the second part to the transcription, otherwise people may pronounce the name as [ˈkʁoː.nɛkɐ]. (Not that that pronunciation wouldn't occur, but people should be aware of the more explicit form.)

Comment: +1. Especially for warning about a typical mistake. I lost count how often I heard German scientists' names butchered to the Oblivion.

Comment: Looks plausible but also like folk etymology? What's your evidence for the etymology? Why is it Kron-Ecker and not Kro-Necker? Is Kroneck/Cronegg explained in the same way? Is it comparable to Honecker? Or is that 'someone from Kroneck'? (A quick search gave me a link saying the origin/meaning of 'Kronecker' was 'not known')

Comment: I think it's more likely that the "Ecker" part is derived from "Ecke" meaning an angle or point. So maybe crown pointer. But I'm guessing that it's actually cognate to 'ackern' meaning to plow, since that's the root of a number of Germanic names, e.g.  [Ackerman](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ackerman_(surname)). Also -egger as in [Schwarzenegger](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwarzenegger_(surname)) is related. Maybe 'royal plowman' then?

Comment: Vieken Dank, Hubert. Das habe ich geglaubt.

Comment: @LangLangC: Kro-Necker doesn't make any sense because "Kro" is neither a German word nor stem of a German word. Kroneck/Kronegg/Cronegg is built from *"Kron"* (stem of *"Krone"* and *"Eck"* (very common variation of *"Ecke"*) (outdated also *"Egg"*) which means *"corner"* but (in Names) also *"ridge".*

Comment: @amadeusamadeus: Das würde bedeuten, dass die Wörter *jede* und *jeder* gleich ausgesprochen werden (ebenso das Paar *eine/einer*). Richtig ist aber: "jede" = [ˈjeːdə], "jeder" = [ˈjeːdɐ] ebenso "eine" =  [ˈaɪ̯nə], "einer" = [ˈaɪ̯nɐ] und auch Davids Minimalpaar: "bitte" = [ˈbɪtə], "bitter" = [ˈbɪtɐ]

Comment: The latter part of your comment should be added to the A-text. However, the first part is still strange for an assumed 'evolution of names'. Also cf https://mathoverflow.net/q/65875/ which seems less concerned with 'Kro is w/o sense'. Here however I'd say that your A implies an internal stop, whereas I still expect a liaison/sandhi to appear, sth like: ˈkʁoː.‿nɛkɐ ?

Comment: @LangLangC: The Question was about pronunciation, not about etymology. I'm not sure about the etymology and I don't want to discuss it. If you're convinced that it comes from Kro + Necker: fine. But it doesn't chance the pronunciation. It still is [ˈkʁoːnɛkɐ]. Three syllables, stress on the first, no glottal stop, no pause and no diphthong. I have a link for you if you want to know more about the etymology of this name: [link](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/ask)

Comment: It is your answer in which you explain pronunciation  with an assumed etymology – which would probably result in a glottal stop before 'e'. And you dismiss other variants, again with etymology, or word-history. My ears tell me that there are three pronunciation variants to consider. You say "It's this, better believe me" and add to your A in debating comments. That is not very convincing. From this thread I leave without knowing the exact pronunciation. I'd suggest to move at least your reasoning here in comments into the answer with an [edit].

Comment: @LangLangC: Separation of spoken syllables very often does not follow etymology. Take my own last name as example: *»Schölnast«*, when spoken, is separed by almost everybody I know in *Schöl + nast.* But the etymology is *Schöln + ast* (*»Schöln«* with a silent L is Middle-Bavarian for *»Schelle«* = small spherical bell and *»Ast«* is a branch of a tree). A *Schöln-ast* is a rhythmical music instrument. But still almost everybody (including me and all of my relatives) separates the syllables of my name as *Schöl + nast.* And the same is true for *Kronecker.*